# Obtaining Azure token from WinLogon

Tags: azure, winlogon

Are there APIs available for Windows App to obtain Azure AD token for the logged in user? So post login can token be accessed by an app?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to get a token, if you are building an UWP App. You need to configure your App Registration in Azure and using that client ID, you can get a Client Bound Access Token with the logged in user's identity.

Microsoft offers [a complete sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/WebAccountManagement).